# LibreOffice slideshow only loops for a few minutes

Tags: libreoffice, raspberrypi

So I have a Raspberry Pi 4 set to auto-present a Impress slideshow, but only cycles the slides for about ~10-20 minutes then stays stuck on one slide. By clicking the mouse or arrow key, it then resumes and continues until it gets stuck on another slide. Does anyone know why it does this? Does the Pi go into a "sleep" mode? Is there a way to prevent this?